# On better understanding the strncpy() function behavior

Tags: c, string, glibc

In the Linux manpage of strncpy I read:

> If the length of src is less than n, strncpy() writes additional
> null bytes to dest to ensure that a total of n bytes are written.

In this limit case (no \0 at the end of both strings) where n>4:

```
    char dest[8]="qqqqqqqq";
    char src[4] = "abcd";
    strncpy(dest, src, 5);
```

printing dest char by char gives "abcdqqqq".
As src has no \0 in it, no \0 is copied from the src to dest, but if I understand correctly the man page, other 4 characters should be copied in any case, and they should be \0s.
Moreover, if src is "abc" (so it is NUL terminated), dest contains "abc\0\0qqq".
I add the whole code I used to test (yes it is going to the 8-th character to look at it also):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char dest[8]="qqqqqqqq";
    char src[4] = "abcd"; //  "abc"
    strncpy(dest, src, 5);
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
        printf("%2x ", dest[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a faulty implementation or do I miss something?

Comment: The answers explain what’s wrong, but you can also run your program with Valgrind to get some indication of the problem (or at least, that there *is* a problem).

Comment: @StephenKitt: I tried clang and `gcc -fsanitize=undefined`, but unsurprisingly they only flag the UB in accessing `dest[8]` in the loop after strncpy.  (The earlier out-of-bounds access happens in library code, not asm actually emitted by this run of GCC, so its extra instrumentation wouldn't catch it since it doesn't inline this `stncpy` even with `-O2`.)

Comment: @Claus: You can pretty much assume that common simple library functions aren't broken on a major mainstream C implementation like gcc + glibc on GNU/Linux.  A more sensible title and phrasing would have assumed that you were missing something and just asked what that was.  If it did turn out that your result was only possible with a broken library implementation, people would then ask you what distro with what build of what gcc and glibc version.  Just like with assembly language questions asking if their CPU is broken, the answer is always no, just flawed understanding.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, build-time sanitisation doesn’t catch it; Valgrind notices the overlapping source and destination in the call to `strncpy`, using its own instrumented `strncpy`.

Comment: @StephenKitt: `-fsanitize=undefined` is not build-time checking.  It adds extra asm to check for runtime stuff like signed-overflow UB and array out-of-bounds.  The fact that the array bounds UB was compile-time-visible at `-O2` was not necessary for it to catch it; it still works with a random or user-input index.  That's also why it only prints as you run the program, not at build time (https://godbolt.org/z/cv1fhK1TY shows it building with no warnings, then running.)  It's a pretty neat feature of recent GCC and clang, but of course not as complete as Valgrind at tracking OoB object access.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah yes, with `libasan` & co (on GCC).

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right, I changed the title. Ty

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If the length of src

That's the problem, your `src` is not a null terminated string so `strncpy` has no idea how long it is. The manpage also has a sample code showing how `strncpy` works: it stops at a null byte and if it doesn't find one it simply keeps reading until it reaches `n`. And in your case it reads the 4 characters of `src` and gets the fifth from `dest` because it's next in memory. (You can try printing `src[4]`, nothing will stop you and you'll get the `q` from `dest`. Isn't C nice?)

Comment: I understand my naïve fault, the **length** of src, computed up to the \0, not the **size** defined in the definition! Ty!

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be using `strncpy()` with a source argument that is not a string but an array of characters. So why do you expect it to behave sensibly? The manual on Linux clearly says it takes a string as the source argument, and that it copies it "including the terminating null byte" (which presumes such a byte). Note that there is no such thing as a "non-terminated string". An array of characters is just an array of characters, and string functions are not guaranteed to work on it.

However, the specific behavior that you are observing is expected and documented.

[The rationale for `strncpy()` in the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncpy.html) contains the following sentence:

> If there is no `NUL` character byte in the first `n` bytes of the array pointed to by `s2`, the result is not null-terminated.

... where `s2` is what you call `src`.

The manual for `strncpy()` on at least Ubuntu and OpenBSD contains similar wordings.

Comment: Explicit-length strings (array of chars and a separately-stored length) are a thing that exists (a data structure that can be implemented in C), and don't *need* to also be valid C strings (implicit length 0-terminated).  But you're right that C doesn't call them strings, so "non-terminated string" doesn't make sense as C terminology, especially in the context of `str...` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at this logically, using quotes from the GNU man page dated 2017-09-15, as included in Debian 10:

> If the length of *src* is less than *n*, **strncpy**() writes additional null bytes to *dest* to ensure that a total of *n* bytes are written.

As you correctly state (sort of), `n == 5`. So what is the “length of *src*”? As we should all know, C strings are null-terminated. The man page hints at this:

> The **strcpy**() function copies the string pointed to by *src*, including the terminating null byte ('\0') … The **strncpy**() function is similar, except that at most *n* bytes of *src* are copied.

Your string is not null-terminated, though. So after reading the 4 bytes you defined, `strncpy` tries to read a fifth byte, and what does it find? The first byte of `dest`, apparently (actually, this is implementation-dependent, as far as I know). It still has not found a null to terminate the string, so does it keep reading? No, because as stated above:

> a total of *n* bytes are written

and

> at most *n* bytes of *src* are copied.

So it copies the 5 bytes `"abcdq"` into `dest`.

You said:

> other 4 characters should be copied in any case, and they should be \0s

This implies a total length of 8 bytes. Where would you get this from? This is the “length” (or at least declared array length) of `dest`, *not* `src`, and in any case would be overridden by the fact that `n < 8`.

The case where `src` *is* null-terminated is straightforward.

So **no, the implementation is not faulty**.

Actually, you got lucky:

> The strings may not overlap

They do here, so, technically, anything could happen. Indeed, a comment on the question says that Valgrind warns about this.

> and the destination string *dest* must be large enough to receive the copy. *Beware of buffer overruns!*

This carelessness with string lengths should be a warning to take extra care, before you create a buffer overrun.

On another note, while it is *possible* that a function like `strncpy` would have a bug, it is *extremely unlikely*. Standard implementations have been thoroughly tested in a wide variety of environments. Any apparent bug is much more likely to a bug in your own code, or a lack of understanding of your own code, as is the case here.